# Conditional loading of snapins in profile

Tags: powershell, command, conditional-statements, loading

We have an internal application that utilizes PowerShell.  In my profile (Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) I have added references to various snap-ins that we've created:

```
#
# Profile for Joe Blow
#
Add-PSSnapIn CompanySnapin
Add-PSSnapin PowerShellTestTools
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnaps -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The problem I'm having is that when I start this internal application, the above lines of code, throw errors.

My question is, is there a way (in my profile script) where I can test WHO or WHAT is trying to open the profile and do things accordingly ?

Example might be:

```
if (!internalApplication)
{
    Add-PSSnapIn CompanySnapin
    Add-PSSnapin PowerShellTestTools
    Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnaps -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

so I get the snapins if I launch the PowerShell command line utility.  Otherwise, nothing is "added".

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on custom app/ host implementation, really. It also means there are at least few ways to skin the cat.

You can start with checking if `$Host.Name` differs.
Next - check if certain properties are present/ set (like `$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor`).

Once you know the difference - you just need to put any code that causes issues in `if {} else {}` and you should be good to go.